# Issue when displaying results from randomization with Mysql row

Tags: php, mysql

So first off, I know this isn't the best method to try and randomize Mysql Rows, but it works for now.

My only issue is that it displays like this: 
**{"0":"random1","quote":"random1"}**
when I want it to display like this
**random1**

My Code:
    `

```
                <?php
                $quotes = $DBcon->query(
                  'SELECT quote FROM quotes ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;');
                $result   = $quotes->fetch_array();
                ?> <strong>Daily Quote</strong> - <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Get Quote" />
                                </div>`
```

*No that is not my only PHP code, but that's the only section for this issue. Also, if I did something wrong, please correct me as I'm still learning.

*

Comment: Don't echo `json_encode` unless you want json formatted text inside your html tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the fetch array return two array one with numeric index and other with string index so use `fetch_assoc()`

```
$result   = $quotes->fetch_array();
```

to

```
$result   = $quotes->fetch_assoc();
```

to display result

```
$result['quote']
```

Comment: Thank you, That fixed the problem of it displaying twice, but why does it appear like this: **{"quote":"quote5"}** instead of **quote5**.

Comment: Now I keep getting: Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\quote.php on line 87
Account Info - 
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\quotes\quote.php on line 88
null